# Navigation can't get display inline

Tags: css

I am having a difficulty displaying my navigation bar inline. Can anybody suggest how to fix it?

```
<nav>
    <ul >
        <li ><%= link_to "Tradery", current_user%></li>
        <li> <%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
            <%= label_tag(:q, "") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
            <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
        <%end%></li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Tradezone", '#' %></li>
        <li> <%= link_to  "Messages", '#' %></li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Notifications", '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to title ="Acount","#" %>
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to "user.business.name", '#'%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "settings", '#'%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "signout", '#'%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "create business",'#'%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "settings", '#'%></li>
                <li><%= link_to "signout", '#'%></li>          
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS for the code:

```
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover> ul{
    display:block;
}
nav ul {
    display:inline-table;
    position:relative;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient
    list-style:none;
    top:100%;
}
```

Comment: try display:inline !important;

Comment: Its still not working..

Comment: try `float:left`. I am sure this might help

Comment: Fix to code indentation

Comment: Please provide enough code for a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

For your `li` tags, add a display of inline-block (took keep them on the same line) and float them left (to remove the blank space between them).

Like so:

```
nav ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope it helps! :-)